# How to make css work for background image on website

Tags: css

I am trying to make background image work like http://www.rottentomatoes.com/ 
I looked at the css used by them which is this:

```
background:url(../Content/themes/base/images/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0px rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

I tried this with background image with resolution of 1280*1024 but it does not work same way at all. It does not cover whole background leaves spaces on both left and right side of the page. Also works differently for all main browsers ie, firefox and chrome. 
Is there a way to make background image like rottoentomatoes for all browsers their background image stays static means if some small text is written on the left of the background image it will be similar in all browsers?

[image: screenshot]
This is the screenshot look at the black background image is not covering whole screen.
I also tried following css:

```
background: url(../Content/themes/base/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

this covers the whole screen but is not consistent on all browsers and ruins the quality of the image. Not at all like rottentomatoes.

[image: rotten]

Added rottentomatoes image to explain what i meant by static text in background image.

Comment: The background image from rottentomatoes works because it has a gradient to its border so that you cannot see where the image ends and the `background-color` begins.

Also, please provide a screenshot.

Comment: @Zeta- added the screenshot. How can i add gradient? I still did not understand what you mean by you cannot see where image begins and ends? But how is their image static on all browsers then? Text is at same place on all browsers?

Comment: @NoviceMe ... I'm not sure what you're talking about.  There isn't any text on the background image of that site:  http://images.rottentomatoescdn.com/images/redesign/bg-clouds.png?v=20120910

Comment: And what Zeta is referring to is the fact that the background essentially terminates to a solid color, so you can set a background-color attribute to match the color which appears as the solid colored edge of your background image.

Comment: @Mike - i added another image to show what i meant by background image being static. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great place to start, ref URL below. When you visit the web page as you scroll down they go through all aspects of aligning the background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                margin-left:200px;
                :#5d9ab2 url('img_tree.png') no-repeat top left;
            }

            .container
            {
                text-align:center;
            }

            .center_div
            {
                border:1px solid gray;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                width:90%;
                background-color:#d0f0f6;
                text-align:left;
                padding:8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Refer Link Check This :- [Css Background In W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)